# Concatenate 1D array to a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a three dimensional array `A`, with shape `(5774,15,100)` and another 1 D array `B` with shape `(5774,)`. I want to add these in order to get the another matrix `C` with shape `(5774,15,101)`.

I am using `hstack` as

```
C = hstack((A ,np.array(B)[:,None]))
```

I am getting the below error, any suggesstions.

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5774,15,100) into shape (5774)
```

Comment: Make `B` (5774,1,1), then repeat to (5774, 15,1), and concatenate on axis 2

Comment: As @hpaulj suggests: `B1 = np.tile(B.reshape(5774, 1, 1), (1, 15, 1))` followed by `C = np.concatenate((A, B1), axis = 2)` should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd need to use `np.concatenate` (which can cancatenate arrays of different shape, unlike the various `np.*stack` methods).  Then, you need to use `np.broadcast_to` to get that `(5774,)` shaped array to `(5774, 15, 1)` (because `concatenate` still needs all the arrays to have the same number of dimensions).

```
C = np.concatenate((A, 
                    np.broadcast_to(np.array(B)[:, None, None], A.shape[:-1] + (1,))), 
                   axis = -1)
```

Checking:

```
A = np.random.rand(5774, 15, 100)
B = np.random.rand(5774)
C = np.concatenate((A, 
                    np.broadcast_to(np.array(B)[:, None, None], A.shape[:-1] + (1,))), 
                   axis = -1)
C.shape

Out: (5774, 15, 101)
```